# Create a SFX archive using python

Tags: python, archive, rar, sfx

I am looking for some help with python script to create a Self Extracting Archive (SFX) an exe file which can be created by WinRar basically.

I would want to archive a folder with password protection and also split volume by 3900 MB so that it can be easily burned to a disk.

I know WinRar has command line parameters to create a archive, but i am not sure how to call it via python anyhelp on this would be of great help.

Here are main things I want:
Archive Format - RAR
Compression Method Normal
Split Volume size, 3900 MB
Password protection

I looked up everywhere but don't seem to find anything around this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [rarfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile/2.6)

Alternatively use something like:

```
from subprocess import call
cmdlineargs = "command -switch1 -switchN archive files.. path_to_extract"
call(["WinRAR"] + cmdlineargs.split())
```

Note in the second line you will need to use the correct command line arguments, the ones above are just as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, I would like to use the WinRar Command line and the syntax is something like below

WinRAR <command> -<switch1> -<switchN> <archive> <files...> <@listfiles...> <path_to_extract\>

I would want to make use of WinRar for my archiving options as it supports even .exe format. But I am confused around calling the above syntax using from Python.

Comment: @user3023515 I have modified the answer to fit the syntax you describe.